# The settings property is of a non-compatible type

Tags: c#, wpf

I set the following property:

```
public Object Value
{
    get
    {
        return AdministrationSettings.Default[settingCode];
    }
    set 
    { 
        AdministrationSettings.Default[settingCode] = value; // <<< Error occurs here
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Value);
    }    
}
```

This property provides the link between the fields of my interface and those of the object AdministrationSettings

AdministrationSettigs represents Settings class .net (having an extension .Settings)

Inside I defined within the properties here is an example:

[image]

When I made ​​the entered data in a field in my interface, here display this interface:

[image]

the program stops at the instruction of line 9, and generates this error:
The settings property "ExclusionZone" is of a non-compatible type, here the code

[image]

the ExclusionZone is one parameter which defined in the .Settings File. its type is double. It is also in the same file (. Settings) they set other parameters, there are those who are of type string, double, Boolean

the problem is only in the Set, for the Get get it's right

I hope there will be someone who can help me

Thanks

Comment: What is 'the instruction conteint local variable value' and what is this 'ExclusionZone'. Please provide us with enough information to help you.

Comment: Sorry, ok Sheridan, instruction is this AdministrationSettings.Default[settingCode] = value;

Comment: So Sheridan I edited my post with the title "The settings property is of a non-compatible type"

Comment: Sorry, there's nothing in your question that explains this problem as far as I can see. Maybe you'd be better off entering the phrase "*C# 'The settings property' 'is of a non-compatible type'*" into a search engine for more help.

Comment: I hope I have explained my problem

Comment: So your `Value` property claims to be able to hold any object, of any possible type, instead of just the `double` type that actually works? What was your reason for that?

Comment: Much, much better... however, can you please clearly explain how `settingCode` is defined and used?

Answer (score 0):

private int value = Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.Setting);

Properties.Settings.Default["Setting"] = value + 1;

This crashed for me but when I changed to value + 1.tostring(); It worked. Ofcourse because my "setting" is of type string. So check that ur value is of the right type :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might want to change the manner in which you are trying to access the application level properties that you defined. 
As alexander points out try: Properties.Settings.Default["PropertyVariable"] instead of AdministrationSettings.Default["PropertyVariable"]

Secondly you have defined three properties namely: (1) ExclusionZone, (2)AlertZone (3)ExcessiveSpeed but you are  trying to access 'settingCode' which is not defined.

Thirdly you are missing inverted commas.

Once you sort these three things, make sure you cast 'value' to the correct data type.

Answer (score 0):

I use ProfileBase to get and maintain extra settings in a user profile.  The ProfileBase object that you get from the ProfileBase.Create() function seems to return something like a dictionary of string-to-string.  Therefore, when I make changes to values and save them, I have to cast them to string, and then call the Save() function on the ProfileBase object.  Here's me saving a bool flag, but first converting it to an int (1 or 0) and then saving that as a string...

```
            ProfileBase pb = ProfileBase.Create(userNew.UserName, true);
            if (pb != null)
            {
                int iCreateFlag = createDefaultDummyAccounts ? 1 : 0;
                pb["CREATEDEFAULTDUMMYACCOUNTS"] = iCreateFlag.ToString();
                pb.Save();
            }
```

If I do not cast iCreateFlag to string, and I try to save the iCreateFlag as an int, I get "The settings property is of a non compatible type", even though my column is defined in the database as INT.  Hope this helps anyone else out with this problem.